# Changing the colors of zsh syntax highlighting - Robbyrussel theme

Tags: colors

Does anyone know how to remove the directory highlighting in ZSH with the robbyrussel theme? This issue is driving me mad lately. Some directories (not all) are being randomly highlighted, and in different colors. Sometimes the highlight color is the same as the text color, which makes the name unreadable. (I'm using iTerm2 on macOS Catalina).

I've tried using the settings:

```
export LSCOLORS=""
and 
DISABLE_LS_COLORS="true"
```

But the directories keep appearing in the same format.

[image: directory highlighting zsh robbyrussel]

Answer (score 0):

That's not the theme that's doing that (which is just a *prompt* theme), but rather the fact that you've set those directories to *world-writable,* which is generally something you shouldn't do. Hence, the intrusive highlighting.

To get them back to normal, do this inside the topmost of the affected dirs:

```bsh
chmod -R og-w .
```

This makes that dir and all its descendents no longer writable to anyone except yourself.